# Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync Permission Denied error

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I am trying displayDialogAsync method by following the link,
https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Office-Dev-Show/Office-Dev-Show-Episode-26-Using-the-Dialog-API-in-Office-Add-ins
When I test the project from GitHub, I got an error "Permission Denied error" at Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync .
Here is a simple code:

```html
    function ShowDialog() {
        // Reference the Form.html file.
        var dialogUrl = 'https://' + location.host + '/Form.html';
        // Display the dialog.
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(dialogUrl, { width: 15, height: 27, requireHTTPS: true }, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                // TODO: Handle error.
                return;
            }

            // Get the dialog and register event handlers.
            var dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (asyncResult) {
                if (asyncResult.type !== Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived) {
                    // TODO: Handle unknown message.
                    return;
                }

                // Parse the message.
                var data = JSON.parse(asyncResult.message);
                showNotification('Hello #Office365Dev', data.name);

                // TODO: Do something with the data.

                // We got our data, time to close the dialog.
                dialog.close();
            });
        });
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

based on the information given, it's not clear which Office app you are running, which version of Office you are running, nor which version of the Office.js you are loading.

The dialog API is only available in the latest click-to-run builds of Office 365 (after 6741) and on the latest Mac release. Be sure that you are on the latest version of Office. The dialog API is not available in all apps, but it should load correctly in Office.js 1.1 for Excel, Word, and PowerPoint. It's slightly different for Outlook. The Office Online apps version of the API is still under development.

The API documentation is online at: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/shared/officeui.md

Comment: thanks for your help. I made a test with Office 2016 msi version, I will try to check whether it is available in click-to-run version.

Comment: For MSI releases, the API should be available by the May update.